# Adding different onClickListener to dynamically creataed Views

Tags: android, click, view, listeners, setting

I am creating an android application, where I am creating 2 imageViews and 2 buttons dynamically , and I want to assign onClickListeners to them and I want to perform different functions for each of them. I have searched all over the internet but there is not information on how to make the views do their own functions on clicking.

So far I have come up with this :

```
    /* Setting the ids */
    leftImageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    rightImageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    sendButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
    setButton.setId(View.generateViewId());

    leftImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    rightImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    setButton.setOnClickListener(this);



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case leftImageView.getId() : 
    }
```

Here is a snap of the error in this code :

[image]

Comment: You have only four view's na..so set ID manually instead of generating with View.

Comment: You cannot have non-constant expressions as cases in your switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id constant -

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.image_view: 
    }
```

or

Use if-else statement instead of switch. it will work fine.

Comment: It is a dynamic button, so it doesn't have an id in R file

Comment: @ayuschjain then use if-else-if instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Multipal `if else` or Can Use `switch`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==leftImageView.getId())
        {

        }
        else
        if(v.getId()==rightImageView.getId())
        {

        }
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.leftimage_view:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a dynamically generated button and does not have a value for id in R.id.* file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a known ID for your buttons like below:

1. Implement in your Activity the View.OnClickListener

   ```
   public class Activity implements View.OnClickListener { }
   ```
2. Generate known ID and register callbacks of the buttons to the OnClickListener

   ```
   leftImageView.setId(1);
   rightImageView.setId(2);
   sendButton.setId(3);
   setButton.setId(4);

   leftImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
   rightImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
   sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   setButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
3. And in your OnClick method should look like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
           case 1:
               // leftImageView is click
               break;
           case 2:
               // rightImageView is click
               break;
           case 3:
               // sendButton is click
               break;
           case 4:
               // setButton is click
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting and getting id's you could simply do:

```
        leftImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        rightImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: yes, but this is redundant. I was looking for a more efficient way of doing it. Here we have just 4 views, they could have been more.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `getId()` method in `onclick`.
Id should be static.

You may assign  some hardcoded id to view and use it in onclicklistener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v){
        case 45: 
        Break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The setId function does not allow me to set a constant integer as ID. It shows the above mentioned error

Comment: just try above. even if it giving red warning, it should work.